# Recursion method printing out too many times?

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, output

so I have a method that recursively sorts through an arrayalist of GeometricObjects and prints them out in order of their areas. However, I can't seem to figure out this little issue. My method is printing out the data properly, but it is printing out the the arraylist 6 times instead of once (It holds 6 objects), any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
private static void recursionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list, int low, int high){
    if (low < high){
        int minIndex = low;
        GeometricObject min = list.get(low); //set min to first object in range
        for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){ //loop through all values other than first
            if (list.get(i).getArea() < min.getArea()){ //check if the value is smaller than current min
                min = list.get(i); //if it is update the min
                minIndex = i; //store min index so we can swap locations later
            }
        }

        Collections.swap(list, low, minIndex); //move the original min to new min's old index (tricky wording)
        list.set(low, min); //set the old lowest to the new lowest using store min value

        recursionSort(list, low + 1, high); //call it again

    }
    System.out.println("Recursion sort:" + list);

}
```

Desired output:

```
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
```

Output I'm receiving

```
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
Recursion sort:[GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=2.0  Area=12.57  Perimeter=12.57 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=4.0  Area=50.27  Perimeter=25.13 ]
, GeometricObject [color=green, filled=false, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=5.0 Width= 11.0  Area=55.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=orange, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=10.0 Width= 6.0  Area=60.0  Perimeter=32.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=red, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Rectangle [ Height=14.0 Width= 12.0  Area=168.0  Perimeter=52.0 ]
, GeometricObject [color=blue, filled=true, dateOfCreation=Wed Oct 14 12:02:33 EDT 2015]
 Circle [ radius=15.0  Area=706.86  Perimeter=94.25 ]
]
```

Comment: You're recursing 6 times, so it's going to print out 6 times. Print it outside of your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that each level of recursion will print out the list before returning.

To fix, you can overload the method to print:

```
private static void recursionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list){
    recursionSort(list, 0, list.size())
    System.out.println("Recursion sort:" + list);        
}

private static void recursionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list, int low, int high){
    if (low < high){
        int minIndex = low;
        GeometricObject min = list.get(low); //set min to first object in range
        for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){ //loop through all values other than first
            if (list.get(i).getArea() < min.getArea()){ //check if the value is smaller than current min
                min = list.get(i); //if it is update the min
                minIndex = i; //store min index so we can swap locations later
            }
        }

        Collections.swap(list, low, minIndex); //move the original min to new min's old index (tricky wording)
        list.set(low, min); //set the old lowest to the new lowest using store min value

        recursionSort(list, low + 1, high); //call it again

    }

}
```

Comment: Well i tried the above and nothing prints, I think i see the idea but the method *private static void recursionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list)* is never used so I'm still kinda stuck.

Comment: Change the place where you call `recursionSort(list, low, high)` to use `recursionSort(list)` instead

Comment: Ahh, I just had to change *recursionSort(list, 0, list.size())* to *recursionSort(list, 0, 5)*, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the list at the end of the recursive method.  Because this occurs on every call, every recursive call will print the list, once the innermost recursive call finishes.

Move the print outside of the recursive method to just after you make the initial recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **returning** the list from your function?

```
public static void main (String args []){
    ArrayList<GeometricObject> list = new ArrayList<GeometricObject>();
    System.out.println(recursionSort(list, 0,list.size()-1).toString());
}

private static ArrayList<GeometricObject> recursionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list, int low, int high){
    if (low < high){
        int minIndex = low;
        GeometricObject min = list.get(low); 
        for (int i = low + 1; i <= high; i++){ 
            if (list.get(i).getArea() < min.getArea()){ 
                min = list.get(i); 
                minIndex = i; 
            }
        }

        Collections.swap(list, low, minIndex);
        list.set(low, min);

        recursionSort(list, low + 1, high);

    }
    return list;

}
```

}

Output:
`[0, 1, 1, 9, 10, 12, 100]`